# How to disconnect user spaces from kernel extension (on the kernel side)

Tags: macos, kernel, kernel-extension, mach

In my kernel extension I am currently supporting, I communicate with user spaces using sockets. So, I subscribe to some callbacks and correctly process them

```
reg.ctl_send = ctl_handle_send; 
reg.ctl_getopt = ctl_handle_getopt;
reg.ctl_setopt = ctl_handle_setopt;

reg.ctl_connect = ctl_handle_connect;
reg.ctl_disconnect = ctl_handle_disconnect;
```

Everything works as expected. Only one problem - I can not unload my kernel extension if there are user space clients that are connected (ctl_deregister(kctlref) returns errors)

Is there a way to override it in kernel extension? I would like to disconnect from ALL clients and successfully unregister myself

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do it with kernel control sockets. You'll need to send a message to userspace and get userspace to close the socket I think.

Comment: I try not to rely on the userspace, because it can be stuck, broken, in infinite loop or whatever.

Comment: You can close sockets in the kernel using `sock_close`. For whatever reason, Apple doesn't give you access to the underlying `socket_t` of a kernel control socket, and there doesn't seem to be a wrapper for the close operation either. If you were to use another type of socket (PF_INET, PF_LOCAL, etc.) directly using the Socket KPI, you should be able to do it.